# How to Implement Asynchronous Processing in a Spring Application for Long-Running Tasks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17

How can I implement **asynchronous processing** in a Java Spring 3-tier application to handle long-running tasks that are expected to take more than **30 seconds**, while providing an immediate response to the client after 30 seconds with the message 'Processing in progress. We will notify you when it's completed'
Then continue the work and processing in the background. Once the background work is completed, I only need to log the completion without sending any further response to the client.

**Note: I work in both JAVA 17 and JAVA 8, so I found most of the functionality didn't work as expected in both of them.**

in my controller, I used this :

```
CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

and also like this

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // return ResponseEntity with the message 'Processing in progress...'
            }
        }, 30000);
```

Comment: Call an `@Async` annotated method. It isn't any harder then that.

Comment: @M.Deinum you can read the question carefully, its not about calling annotation.

Comment: Yes it is. Call an `@Async` annotated method from the controller, it will return immediatly while the task keeps running. So it is exactbly about that. You can return a `CompletableFuture` if you want (or use a defferedresult) and set a timeout. Which will then return. If that isn't the case then provide additional information what you have tried (as you stated your chosen solutions didn't work).

Comment: Yes, I understand u . In my implementation, I have placed the @Async annotation on the service method rather than in the controller. This choice is based on the fact that most of the time-consuming operations are typically performed in the service layer to keep controllers lean and focused on handling HTTP requests.

In the service layer, I have replaced the return type from List<myObject> to CompletableFuture<List<myObject>>. This allows me to execute the method asynchronously.

Check the question , I put some of my code on it

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you think it does. Just execute the async method. Nothing more nothing less. You are making things overly complex. As stated just annotate your service method and be done. Also the code you posted doesn't make anything clear it only shows delated execution and some timer, all working around the `@Async` from spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum but what about providing an immediate response to the client after 30 seconds with the message, i need the response to become send for frontend side for example as a message inside the object? and completing the work in the background ? also you said i need Just execute the async method - service method -, but what about the data type in the service, to keep it as it is. ?

Comment: What datatype/ You haven't posted any of the classes you are referring to. As I stated return a completablefuture, in the controller use a deferredresult with a timeout of 30 seconds. That is it, nothing more, nothiong less.

Comment: this steps i will go with 
In the service layer, execute the asynchronous method and return a CompletableFuture for the result.
In the controller, use a DeferredResult with a timeout of 30 seconds.
If the timeout occurs, return a response with the status "Processing in progress..." and complete the work in the background asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things overly complex. You should be calling an `@Async` service method, which would return a `CompletableFuture` (or you can inject the `AsyncTaskExecutor` and use the `submitCompletable` to wrap the service call (instead of annotating it with `@Async` and return a `CompletableFuture`).

In the controller use a `DeferredResult` which will send the result as soon as it is available from the `CompletableFuture` through the `CompletableFuture` callback methods. It will also have an `onTimeout` callback (for 30 seconds) which will fire if the process didn't finish within 30 seconds. It will keep the background process running but will return an answer to the client.

```java
// Deferred Result with 30 second timeout
DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> result = new DeferredResult(30_000, () -> ResponseEntity.accepted().body("Processing").build());
CompletableFuture<YourResult> future = ... // However you achieve this
future.whenComplete( (res, ex) -> {
  if (res != null) {
    res.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok(res));
  } else {
    res.setErrorResult(ex);
  }
});
return result;
```

Something along those lines. The `DeferredResult` will wait for 30 seconds, if not return a default response (HTTP 200 ACCEPTED with a message, when the `CompletableFuture` completes it will return a regular response, or if it was an exception return that).

Comment: I did what you said and its working, thanks alot.. but I had small problem, I have to return object, let say its student with Id, if the response taken over 30 return in progress in the Id, if not return the real Id, I did it to set the end of code :

` // Create a DeferredResult with a 30-second timeout
        DeferredResult<StudentIdUrl> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(30_000L);

        // Set the DeferredResult's result to the timeout response
        deferredResult.setResult(studentDataResult); `

Comment: where studentDataResult set in beginning of class as         studentDataResult.setMessage("In progress...");
and in the  .whenComplete changed,

Comment: why always returining in progress ? it not changed, and in postman it takes time less than 30 secs

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to express in these comments. You specifically requested for that. *roviding an immediate response to the client after 30 seconds with the message 'Processing in progress. We will notify you when it's completed'* That was your own request, to return a message after 30 seconds.

Comment: This works, thx!  A note for other users : the default timeout of the DeferredResult seems to be 30 seconds, so set your own value if needed (or use the default constructor without parameters if 30 seconds is fine).

Comment: Another note: when working with the Exceptions : they are wrapped in a CompletionException , so to trigger your exceptionhandlers (which are class-based) , make sure to get the source : res.setErrorResult(ex.getCause()); when following above example.